# Deleting whitespace from a string via an iterator to the string in a C++11 range-based for loop

Tags: c++, string, c++11, iterator, auto

I'm simply trying to delete all the whitespace from a string using C++11's range-based for loop; however, I keep getting `std::out_of_range` on `basic_string::erase`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(){

  std::string str{"hello my name is sam"};

  //compiles, but throws an out_of_range exception
  for(auto i : str){
    std::cout << typeid(i).name();  //gcc outputs 'c' for 'char'
    if(isspace(i)){
      str.erase(i);
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  //does not compile - "invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'char')"
  for(auto i : str){
    if(isspace(*i)){
      str.erase(i);
    }
  }

  //works exactly as expected
  for(std::string::iterator i = begin(str); i != end(str); ++i){
    std::cout << typeid(*i).name();  //gcc outputs 'c' for 'char'
    if(isspace(*i)){
      str.erase(i);
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

So I'm wondering:  what exactly is `i` in the first two loops?  Why is it seemingly both a `char` (as verified by `typeid`) and an `iterator` to a `char` (works with `std::string::erase`)? Why isn't it equivalent to the `iterator` in the last loop?  It seems to me that they should function exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `i` in the range-based `for` loop is `char`, since the elements of a string are characters (more formally, `std::string::value_type` is an alias for `char`).

The reason why it *seems* to work as an iterator when you pass it to `erase()` is that an [overload of `erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) exists that accepts an index and a count, but the latter has a default argument:

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

And on your implementation `char` happens to be implicitly convertible to `std::string::size_type`. However, this is likely *not* doing what you expect.

To verify that `i` is not indeed an iterator, try dereferencing it and you will see the compiler screaming:

```
*i; // This will cause an error
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the for-loop given at the end may not work correctly, because `erase` can invalidate the loop iterator. To fix this, you can use the iterator that `erase` returns, although if used naively this may lead to poor performance (the loop will be worst-case quadratic instead of linear time, because erase is itself worse-case linear). For efficiency you should use `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`, or a similar implementation, as suggested in @syam's answer (edit: which has since been deleted).

Comment: @JohnBartholomew: Good point. My answer mostly focused on the first questions in the last paragraph, I did not delve into a deeper analysis :) Thank you for your pointing out